# Nested resources in grape / swagger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, ruby-grape

In the project I'm using

```rb
gem 'grape'
gem 'grape-swagger'
```

I have a namespace in the API that is responsible for the users END-points

```rb
namespace :users do
  mount V1::Users::AuthAPI
  mount V1::Users::MaterialsAPI
  ...
end
```

Each of the mounted files has its own namespace, for example `app/api/v1/users/materials_api.rb`

```rb
namespace :materials do
  ...
end
```

In the swagger documentation, this is displayed in such a way that all paths belong to the users namespace

[image]

How can I break these paths into sections?

Comment: By sections you mean, the way you have `users` to show another one with `materials`?

Comment: At now the section name is "users" with desc "Operations about users" and all END-points are here. I would like to have separdated sections for "materials", "authentication", etc., each of which has its own END-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I haven't used grape-swagger,  you can achieve that by using `tags` and assigning to each endpoint a `tag`.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
....
tags:
  - name: users
   description: something about users
  - name: materials
   description: something about materials
paths:
  /api/v1/users/auth:
    post:
     tags:
       - users
     ...
  /api/v1/users/materials:
    get:
      tags:
        - materials
     ....
```

That config should render something like this:

[image]

I see grape-swagger has this https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger#tags-

Comment: Yes, thanks, I specified the tags in `desc` block and everything worked out. It's a little strange why it works like this (why by default is the tag taken only from the first namespace), but it worked, thanks